# Center text around specific word in table cell using Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsattributedstring, text-alignment

I have a UITableView with multiple cells, each containing a sentence of attributed text. I would like to know how to centre the text in each of these cells around a specific word contained in those sentences.

The result would be a central column of the word but each cell containing different surrounding words.

I'm guessing the place to start is to centre the text in the cell array but doing so in the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" delegate method with the line:

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    self.cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")


    if(cell.isEqual(NSNull)) {
        self.cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("cell", owner: self,        options: nil)[0] as! UITableViewCell;
    }
        self.cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.synonymsCategories[indexPath.row]!
        self.cell.textLabel?.attributedText =     self.synonymsContext[indexPath.row]
        self.cell.detailTextLabel?.textAlignment = .Right

        self.cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        self.cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        return self.cell as UITableViewCell

}
```

But no changes I make to "self.cell.textLabel" produce any visual changes at run time.

Any ideas? Any help much appreciated.

Felix

Comment: You could use a `NS(Mutable)ParagraphStyle` to do it. Also, I didn't check, but if you color the background of `textLabel` does it take the whole "width" or is it resized to just fit in width?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but nothing i do to textLabel has any visual effect, whether it be the  background colour or the alignment. I've updated the code in the question to include the full delegate method.